# What's the origin of the expression "Lombardi dad"?

Tags: expressions, idioms, phrase-origin

"Grant says Tiger Mothers and Lombardi Dads often focus on achievements because they're easy to measure."

http://www.wnyc.org/story/raising-caring-children/

Comment: It's not an established usage, but I suppose the reference is to [Vince Lombardi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vince_Lombardi) (a US sports coach, presumably much preoccupied with helping people to *achieve* things).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an obscure cultural reference, not directly related to "use of English".

Comment: Note that [tiger mothers](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_dc6DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA60&dq=%22tiger+mothers%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22tiger%20mothers%22&f=false) is at least a *little* better known. It refers to East Asian mothers (Koreans in particular) who put a lot of pressure on their children to perform well academically.

Comment: @FumbleFingers even if the reference is obscure, the OP didn't know that. How often do we see names of people or animals that become idiomatic in English http://abceda.com/nameidiom.htm

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: As I said, ***it's not an established usage**.* I'd never heard of Vince Lombardi before I looked at this question, but his Wikipedia page came up top of the list when I googled **Lombardi dad**, so I figured it out from there. I was able to guess what **tiger moms** would mean (by association with **tiger economies** and such), so I had some idea of what *kind* of meaning might be involved. Nevertheless, this isn't a matter of language use as such - it's a cultural reference which I'm sure would be meaningless to the vast majority of native Anglophones.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I get that it's not well-known, although I'm surprised you aren't familiar with "tiger moms", it's related to [***Tiger Woods'***](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22Tiger+Woods+mom%22) "mom", and manager ( I think) who is ***Thai***. I think it really came into prominence thanks to her. In any case, surely the answer to the question is "It is not an idiom" and explain why the name was used.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I can see that Tiger Woods' mom might have influenced later take-up, but this 1980 reference to [alumni and Tiger moms](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22alumni+and+Tiger+moms%22) suggests the usage was already established, so I still think it's a variant of ***tiger economy***. I hadn't actually registered the ***Thai*** alliteration before now, but I would just say that the original [Four Asian Tigers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Asian_Tigers) (Hong Kong, Singapore, South Korea and Taiwan) doesn't include Thailand.

Comment: No, no, no, *tiger mothers* in popular culture has nothing to do with Tiger Woods, or Confucian allegories. Amy Chua's 2011 memoir *Battle Hymn of the Tiger Mother* about her strict upbringing in a Chinese-American household received very considerable attention in the U.S. (naturally, the most strident commentary in favor and against seems to come from people who haven't actually read it).

Answer (score 2):

I never heard of this expression before, but I did some research on it and think I have the answer.

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vince_Lombardi#Family_life) Wikipedia article, *Vince Lombardi* was a famed football coach with a high sense of "perfectionism, authoritarian nature, and temper". In his role as a father, he would fit your idiom perfectly. According to [this](http://www.vincelombardi.com/about.html) fan page, "he conducted grueling training camps and demanded absolute dedication and effort from his players".

The coup de grâce: In an interview [here](http://newsok.com/article/3538604), Lombardi's son, Vince Lombardi Jr., described his father as having "not so great qualities for a father from the standpoint of his only son".

The expression doesn't appear to be common, however. Google NGrams has no results for any variations of "lombardi dad", and Google Trends show searches for the topic below one hundred per month. It might even have been made up on the spot; the author of your article was once described [here](https://faculty.wharton.upenn.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/AdamGrant-AmericanPsychologist.pdf) as "too weak for football", showing that he at least had an interest in the sport, and according to [here](http://www.management.wharton.upenn.edu/grant/AdamGrantCV.pdf) he once taught a seminar in April 2012 titled *National Football League “Motivation and engagement”*. Perhaps the author was just struck by a whimsical desire to display his football knowledge, and perhaps not. It does, however, seem self-evident that the term referred to Vince Lombardi.

Comment: It may indeed have been made up on the spot, in an effort to find a counterpart to Tiger Moms.  The author argues that Tiger Moms and Lombardi Dads focus too much on achievement, not enough on effort.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winning_isn%27t_everything;_it%27s_the_only_thing):

> "Winning isn’t everything; it’s the only thing" [...] is widely, but wrongly attributed to American football coach Vince Lombardi.